# How to Generate Documentation for node project

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, jsdoc, toolkit

I am trying to create documentation for simple node project and want to generate doc for only 3 files.

> 1. routes.js
> 2. controller.js
> 3. model.js

simple code of routes.js

```
/**
Holds code to route the brand specific APIs to the right functions
*/ *

 var express = require('express'); 
 var router = express.Router();
 const brandController = require('../controllers/brand');
 const tokenAuth = require('../lib/tokenAuth');
 const permission = require('../lib/checkAccess');

 router.post('/addBrand',tokenAuth.EmployeeValidateToken,permission.attributeWriteAccess, brandController.addBrand);

 router.get('/brandList', brandController.getBrands);
```

and I'm using middelware in routes.js

code of  controller.js

```
 const brandModel = require('../models/brand');
 var brandController = {};

/**
  *This is a function for add brand information
  * @param {object} req
  * @param {object} res
  *@returns {object}
*/

brandController.addBrand = (req, res) => {
   if(req.body.name != undefined){
     let name = req.body.name
     req.body.sortNm = name.toLowerCase();
   }
   let storeData = new brandModel(req.body);
   storeData.save((err, brand) => {
     if(err || brand == null ) {
        console.log("addbrand: brand could not be inserted:"+ brand);
        console.log("err", err);
        if (err){
            return res.json(400,{"data" :err})
        } else{
            return res.json(200,{"data" :brand})
        }
    } else{
            return res.json(200,{"data" :brand})
    }
})

/**
  * This is a function get all brand information based on condition
  * @param {Object} req
  * @param {Object} res
  * @returns {object}
*/


brandController.getBrands = (req, res)=>{
  let condition = {}; 
  console.log("req.query.data",req.query.data)
  console.log("page", req.query.page);
  console.log("limit", req.query.limit);
  var skipValue, limitValue;

  if(req.query.page != undefined && req.query.page > 1){
     console.log("if");
     skipValue = 10 *(req.query.page -1);
     limitValue = 10;
  }
  else{
     console.log("else");
     limitValue = req.query.page == 1? 10: 1000;
     skipValue = 0;
   }

  if(req.query.limit != undefined){
      limitValue = req.query.limit;
  }

 var dta = new RegExp('^'+req.query.data, "i");
 console.log("limitValue==" + limitValue + "skipValue==" + skipValue);
 condition = (req.query.data != undefined) ?{$and:[{'sortNm':{$regex:dta}},{'isActive':true}]}: {'isActive':true}
 console.log("condition", condition);
 brandModel.find(condition, (err, data) =>{
    if(err || data == null ) {
        console.log("getBrand: brand could not be fetched:"+ data);
        console.log("error", err);
        if (err){
            return res.json(400,{"data" :err})
        } else{
            return res.json(400,{"data" :data})
        }
    } else{
        // console.log("response data", data);
        brandModel.count(condition, (err, count)=>{
            console.log("count", count);
            totalPages = Math.ceil((count) / 10);
            totalPages = totalPages == 0 ? 1 : totalPages;
            return res.json(200, {
                data: data,
                totalPages: totalPages
            })
        })
    }
  }).limit(limitValue).skip(skipValue).sort({'seq':-1})



module.exports = brandController;
```

code of model.js

```
/**
 * Model for the brand collection.
 * It is used to perform any db operations on brand collection
 * @module models/brand
*/ 

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var autoIncrement = require('mongoose-auto-increment');

var brandSchema = new Schema({
  name : {type:String, required: true},
  isActive: {type:Boolean, default:true, required: false},
  seq: { type: Number},
  sortNm : {type: String, required: false, trim: true}
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Brand', brandSchema);
```

Comment: you can use npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdoc as written here

Comment: or you can use readme file in node project